# How manage focus and blur in Angular 17 and Angular Materials

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus, blur

1. I want to manage focus in my app. In login i want, thats field 'code' focused, after server return result 'true"

```
  @ViewChild('telephone') telephone!:ElementRef<any>
  @ViewChild('code') code!:ElementRef<any>
...
if (response.body.result) {
          this.frm.controls['codeField'].enable();
          this.renderer.selectRootElement('#code').focus()
}

HTML:
<mat-form-field class="codeField" >
        <mat-label>Code</mat-label>
        <span matPrefix> &nbsp;</span>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="00-00" mask="00-00" formControlName="codeField"  id='code' >
    </mat-form-field>
```

I have tried to use:

```
renderer.selectRootElement('#focus').focus()/click()
ElementRef.nativeElement.focus()/click()
MatInput.focus()/click()
```

2. I want to manage blur in my app. I want, that's 'address' and the 'room' blurred, after user select.

```
@ViewChild('address') adressInput!: MatAutocomplete;
@ViewChild('room') roomInput!: MatAutocomplete;

TS:
address_is_selected(event: any) {
 this.address.blur()

HTML:
<mat-form-field layout-align='center center'>
                <input matInput placeholder="address" aria-label="address" [matAutocomplete]="address"
                        formControlName="adress" #addressInput/>
                    <mat-autocomplete #address="matAutocomplete" id="address" (optionSelected)="address_is_selected($event.option.value)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let addressof filteredaddress | async" [value]="address">
                            <span> {{ address}}</span>
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I tried all of these methods, but no one of them can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A template reference variable it's used to get the ViewChild, but it's not an html attribute. In .ts you use **the variable** and gets the ElementRef. but you use the "template reference variable" (without the "#")

So if you write "see the #addressInput" **in** the "matInput"

```
<input #addressInput matInput.../>
```

You get it

```
@ViewChild('addressInput') address!:ElementRef
```

The elementRef.nativeElement is the HTMLElement

So you simply use "javaScript"

```
   //see that you use the "variable"
   this.address.nativeElement.focus()
```

Another way is "pass" the HTMLElement in your submit function, put be carefull, in this case the variable is the own HTMLElement

```
<form [formGroup]="form"  (submit)="submit(form,addressInput)">
  ...
</form>

submit(form:FormGroup,el:HTMLElement)
{
   ...do something, e.g....
   if (form.valid)
   {
       this.service.saveData(form.value).subscribe(res=>{
           if (res.succesfull)
               el.focus() //<--see that directly
       })
   }
   else
   {
      form.updateValueAndValidity();
      el.focus()
   }
}
```

Comment: It works only in ngMethods, like ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit. I need that's it work in me own methods. And it causes the error 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError'. How i can to resolve this problem?

Comment: I tried to add click on hidden button, but this, don't work. Keyboard and focus still stay.

Comment: Works in any function you declare in the .ts of the **component**. See that you use the **variable** declare in .ts, not the template reference variable. The only is that "ViewChild" only have value if the element it's yet in the "screen". The error 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' happens when Angular can not be sure the variables in .ts are the same is showed in screen. Generally you can not take account of this, but always can enclosed all under a `setTimeout:setTimeout(()=>{..your code here..})` if disturbt you.